# How to pass external variables to python program with variable names?

Tags: python

I want to pass  external variables to my python script with variable names.

If I pass like:

```
program.py 'var1' 'var2' 'var3'
```

then the problem is: if var2 by mistake is space (without quotes) then python script taking var3 as value instead of var2.

expected way to pass variables is :

```
program.py a=var1 b=var2 c=var3
```

so that if var2 is space(without quotes) python program will take var2 value as space only, doesn't pick var3 instead of var2.

Comment: I think you are looking for `argparse` such as: [Python file keyword argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33902937/8150685)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python file keyword argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33902860/python-file-keyword-argument)

Comment: @Syntactical Remorse Thank you so much, I could answer my question myself down, with help of your question link you shared.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to accept command line arguments or use command line arguments to fill variables already inside a program?

For the former, use [argparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html), it's pretty easy to parse both `<opt> <arg>` and `<opt>=<arg>` formats.

For the latter however, you can do this via the example below, but it's a security vulnerability:

```
>>> exec('a=3')
>>> a
3
>>> import sys
>>> cli_args = sys.argv[1:]
>>> exec(cli_args[0]) 
>>>
```

Basically, you can use the `exec()` function in python to execute string statements like `'a=4'`, but doing so will allow code injection in your program. If someone knows you are using `exec()` on cli args, they could put malicious code inside the cli options that will be executed by your program.

That's why it's more recommended to just parse command line options.

Answer (score 0):

```
[root]# cat t.py 

import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()


parser.add_argument('v1')
parser.add_argument('v2')

args = parser.parse_args()

print ('value of variable a is:',args.v1)
print ('value of variable b is:',args.v2)
```

**Executing above script:**

```
[root]# python3 t.py v1='abc' v2=3
value of variable v1 is: v1=abc
value of variable v2 is: v2=3
```

**Same Using python2:**

```
[root]# python t.py v1=abc v2=3
('value of variable v1 is:', 'v1=abc')
('value of variable v2 is:', 'v2=3')
```